# Accurately polygon tree canopy foot print using MultiSpectral data & polygons where trees and grass have similar spectral signature using QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis-3, raster-calculator, ndvi, zonal-statistics

**QUESTION:** How to accurately polygon tree canopy foot print using Multi-Spectral data where trees and grass have similar spectral signature using QGIS 3.22

Contained in here is a series of photos as background information finishing with Picture 7 showing end goal.

**Background Info**
I have a young tree orchard of 9000 trees where I want to place a polygon around the canopy foot print of the tree so I can undertake a 12 month longitudinal study to establish a "tree health decline curve" by analyzing only the data within each tree canopy polygon.

Hopefully this curve can be used to identify and proactively intervene declining trees earlier.

Data I have available is 5cm pixel resolution geo tiff bands of R/G/B/NIR/RE and I have NDVI and OSAVI calculated Layers. I also have a digital surface model for heights.

***The issue I have is don't know how to accurately define just the Tree canopy footprint from grass where the spectral signature is the same.***

**Photo 1** of the land. Trees clearly distinguishable
[image: Photo of Trees]

**Photo 2** This is OSAVI (grey scale) Trees clearly distinguishable. Formula is (NIR+Red)/NIR+Red + 0.16). Parts of the grass and trees have similar values

[image: OSAVI - Grey]

**Photo 3** This is the same area as OSAVI (single band Pseudo color)The Grass has the same signature as the trees (shades of white, pink and red).

[image: OSAVI (single band Pseudo color)]

**Photo 4a** *Profile line* This is the data from the DSM.

Can Tree height be used with other data to separate Trees canopy footprint from other vegetation?
[image: DSM Data]

**Photo 4b**
*Graph of the profile showing tree heights.*

[image: profile graph]

**Photo 5* I also have points indicating each tree. Done Manually
[image: Tree points]

**Photo 6** Zonal Statistics done using these buffer tool to create polygons, but I am getting ground data from within the polygons which is what I want to avoid and just have Tree canopy data inside the Polygons.

[image: Zonal Stats - polygons]

**Photo 7** This is ideally what I am trying to end up with across all 9000 trees

[image: ideal end result]

Comment: I think that to solve this problem would require training the neural network on all available spectral channels.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was hoping it was a little simpler than that. Maybe using a calculation of DSM data and say OSAVI to differentiate between where the OSAVI is the same for tree and Grass but the height is 1-2m above the surrounding ground point indication it is a tree and then using polygonize tool.

Comment: I'd be tempted to do something to normalise your height into a 0-1 range and then multiply that with OSAVI. Anything above a threshold could then be classified as canopy.

Comment: Do you know how to in Raster Calc to set all pixels > 16 meters to a value of 0m and leave everything < 16m their current value? I need to flatten sheds, tree wind breaks and Water tanks to 0m before creating a binary raster file.

Comment: @AAuld Try this: `IF ("RASTER@1"  >  16 , 0, "RASTER@1")`